# Javascript: Change <img> in a loop with fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making an photography website and i am stuck. I am looking for somebody to rescue me. 
My problem is the next one : I wanna translate the next code from CSS into javascript.

```
img#image {
    margin: 0px;
    background-repeat: none;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}
```

I have'd made until now :

```
function Rotate(randomImage) {
            document.getElementById('image').src = randomImage;
            document.getElementById('image').setAttribute("style","height: 100%; width: 100%; position:relative; z-index:-1;    -webkit-animation-name: fade;-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;animation-name: fade;animation-duration: 1.5s;");
        }
```

I need to add @-webkit-keyframes fade and @keyframes fade to my javascript code. Thank you !

Comment: why do you want to use javascript though. CSS animation is much efficient and same fadeIn/fadeOut slider can be achieved through CSS.

Comment: Because i wanna make an automatic slider in javascript. The effect works just when i refresh the page, when the javascript code intervenes, the effect is not working any more.

Comment: But for this you do not need to add any javascript code, so there should be no intervention. I mean you can create this automatic slider with css alone e.g. on this site http://charanjeet.com/ . And I think you say you already have achieved that. So why do you want to use javascript then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways then using JS, however you can use the following :

```
    <div id ="myImg" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:blue;"></div>

<script>
  function fadeIn(from,to,duration) {
      var elem = document.getElementById("myImg"); 
      var step = (to-from)/duration;
      var opacity = from;
      var id = setInterval(frameFade, 5);

      function frameFade() {
          if (opacity >= to) {
              clearInterval(id);
          } else {
              opacity+=step; 
              elem.style.opacity = opacity; 
              elem.innerHtml = opacity;
          }
      }
  }
  fadeIn(0.4,1.0,500);
</script>
```

[plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/JElwtsc2fhfQ7SUZB6AI?p=preview)

Comment: Your answear helped me the most ! I am very new to web development,  and if this works, I am happy. Thank you.

Comment: One more question. If my website tab is not in focus, the effects is counting up and when i am returning to him, the fade is starting to go a little crazy.

Comment: can you please share a link or code to how you run it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a `Dom` animation use like this

```
document.getElementById('image').animation='fade 1.5s'
document.getElementById('image').WebkitAnimation='fade 1.5s'
```

For changing more number of style Better use with [`classList.add()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp) for pure javascript

```
function Rotate(randomImage) {
  document.getElementById('image').src = randomImage;
  document.getElementById('image').classList.add('animation_class')

}
```

**For jquery [`addClass()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwigst-g6tjTAhUHr48KHfqbC7EQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Faddclass%2F&usg=AFQjCNH6-3zbJdemq41CpsMTonaIdGjKwQ)**

```
function Rotate(randomImage){
 $('img').attr('src',randomImage).addClass('animation_class')
}
```

**Css**

```
.animation_class {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
```

Comment: It is a great ideea, this is what i was looking for. But, the problem remains. The effect is working just when i refresh the browser. If i let the loop doing it's job, there is no more any king of effect.